# Обновление mysql

Tags: php, mysql, сервер, веб-сервер

После обновления версии mysql по [этой статье](https://support-tech.info/linux/obnovlenie-php-i-mysql-mariadb-na-centos-6-7/) и перезагрузки сервера, перестало заходить по старым доступам в бд и на сайтах пишет нет подключения к бд. Через терминал тоже не могу залогиниться. Под рутом просит пароль. Подскажите, как всё вернуть. Работало всё на mysql 55 и php 74.
Любые манипуляции с mysql через терминал, приводят к ошибке

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

Comment: Вы же сделали резервную копию БД как указано в инструкции? Значит все данные целы. Откатите БД на исходную.

Comment: @becouse нет, не сделал. Может систему можно как-то откатить на день назад?

Comment: Так как у вас есть доступ на сервер ищите как сменить рута мускула. Дальше оазберетесь. Откатить никак.

Comment: Смотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: Вероятно у вас поменялась ссылка на MySQL исполняемый файл (тоже так было на днях при обновлении PHP). В итоге получается что у вас установилась новая версия с шаблонным конфигом, и на неё указывает ссылка в /var/run. Вы можете: 1. Поменять ссылку на предыдущую версию чтобы всё стало как было, выкачать доступы, схемы и данные и сделать миграцию. 2. Заново пересоздать всё с нуля. И не забудьте что в этой ссылке нет ничего про восстановление пользователей и их прав.